# i want "code" =10 change into "code"= "10" in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, string

```
[{"code":10,"shtdesc":"CoOrdHR","name":"CO-ORDINATOR - HR","isselect":0}]
```

change

```
(int to string)=> particular value "code"=10-> "code"="10" , "isselect":0->"isselect":"0"
```

I want output to be

```
[{"code":"10","shtdesc":"CoOrdHR","name":"CO-ORDINATOR - HR","isselect":"0"}]
```

Comment: this question is not really clear. JSON has no functions by itself. you need to use a programming language or a tool to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var data = [{"code":10,"shtdesc":"CoOrdHR","name":"CO-ORDINATOR - HR","isselect":0}];

data[0].code = String(data[0].code);
```

If you want to change all properties to strings, in all elements of the array, then

```
function change_properties_to_strings(arr) {
  return arr.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
      obj[key] = String(obj[key]);
    });
  });
}
```

In other words, loop over the elements of the array, each of which is an object. For each object, loop over its keys (property names). For each key, change the value of the that property to a string.

If you prefer for-loops, using the same logic you can write:

```
function change_properties_to_strings(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    for (var k in obj) {
      obj[k] = String(obj[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

I would remove all opening and close brace/brackets then split by `",|:"`.  Iterate through the array, from the split, adding quotes around a value if they're not there, while adding them back to a newly constructed json `String`.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "[{\"code\":10,\"shtdesc\":\"CoOrdHR\",\"name\":\"CO-ORDINATOR - HR\",\"isselect\":0}]";
    // Split out each value
    String[] jsonPieces = json.replaceAll("[\\[\\]{}]", "").split(",|:");

    // Reconstruct json
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[{");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonPieces.length; i++) {
        // Add quotes if they're not there
        if (!jsonPieces[i].startsWith("\"")) {
            jsonPieces[i] = "\"" + jsonPieces[i] + "\"";
        }
        // Append json piece
        sb.append(jsonPieces[i]);

        // Append ":" or "," 
        if (i + 1 < jsonPieces.length) {
            sb.append(i % 2 == 0 ? ":" : ",");
        } 
    }
    // Append closing
    sb.append("}]");

    // Reassign back to json
    json = sb.toString();

    // Display results
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Results:

```
[{"code":"10","shtdesc":"CoOrdHR","name":"CO-ORDINATOR - HR","isselect":"0"}]
```

Comment: Essentially, you're duplicating the functionality of a JSON library, not a very robust solution.

Comment: @torazaburo Your point is taken.  At the time this question was posted, there was no preferable language tagged or mentioning that the JSON library had to be used, so I just proposed a possible raw solution in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

```js
var arr = [{
  "code": 10,
  "shtdesc": "CoOrdHR",
  "name": "CO-ORDINATOR - HR",
  "isselect": 0
}];

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));

var transform = function(list) {
  var l = list.length;
  var o;
  while (l--) { //loop through each json
    o = list[l];
    for (var k in o) // loop through each key in json
      if ('number' === (typeof o[k])) // only if property value is number
        o[k] = o[k].toString();
  }
  return list;
};

alert(JSON.stringify(transform(arr)));
```